# SOQL ORDER BY - 2 Fields?

Tags: soql, sql

I'm looking for a way to achieve this in SOQL:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532599/need-to-perform-order-by-twice

I'd like to order by the Priority field on Case, otherwise order by Age of Case

So for example:

```
Priority - Age of Case

Urgent , 5
Urgent , 4
High   , 7
High   , 6
Low    , 17
Low    , 10
Low    , 5
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: 20 seconds after posting I found the syntax is `ORDER BY Field1, Field2`. Accepted answer goes to first who posts a link to the documentation where this is detailed

Comment: SELECT Priority ,  Age of Case FROM Case ORDER BY Priority ASC,  Age of Case DESC ?

"Multiple column sorting is supported, by listing more than one fieldExpression clause."

As per documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to separate fields with comma like this :

```
ORDER BY YOURFIELD1, YOURFIELD2
```

See the documentation :
http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/sorting-query-results

Answer (score 10):

Since `Priority` is type text, you could not order in a way explained. It would order alphabetically.

e.g., `High -> Low -> Urgent (Alphabetically)`

So, you could create one more field that is numeric and can be sorted.

```
Priority: 1 (Urgent), 2 (High), 3 (Low)
```

Then you could write SOQL like:

```
SELECT Priority__c, Priority_Number__c, Age__c FROM Object__c ORDER BY Priority_Number__c ASC, Age__c ASC
```

Comment: Thanks San. It's an ordered pick-list so in my case it works, but you make a good point! +1